# "following" or "according to"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, sentence-construction

I would like to know if I should use **following** or **according to** when referring to some guidelines, such as in the following example:

> Stunting was diagnosed when a patient’s height was smaller than 1.40m,
>   for men, or 1.30m, for women. These cut-off points were defined
>   **following** / **according to** World Health Organization guidelines on
>   anthropometry.

Comment: Often, according to is placed at the beginning. I would not use following here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is correct in this context, it's a stylistic choice. Personally I would add "the" if you went with "following", thus "defined following the World Health Organization guidelines...", but I would leave it off if you went with "according to", thus "defined according to World Health Organization guidelines..."

Answer (score 0):

In this case either is fine. Bear in mind though you forgot your article **the**.

> Stunting was diagnosed when a patient’s height was smaller than 1.40m, for men, or 1.30m, for women. These cut-off points were defined **following / according to the** World Health Organization guidelines on anthropometry.

Comment: The article is optional. The sentence works either with it or without it.